# How to add custom property in SlickGrid grouping?

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

For my project I'm using draggable grouping. My requirement is that I should hide the column from the grid once it is grouped and add
it back again to the grid once it is removed from the grouping. I'm doing this work inside onGroupChanged event callback
for which I need some custom params, which gives me some information about the columns that are grouped which I will use as a param
to the hide column method and some other validations. The onGroupChanged event args gives everything that is given inside the grouping object inside columndefinition.
So if I can get a provision to set a custom param inside the grouping object in the columndefinition, I will use it for my
operation. If there are any other way to achieve this kindly tell me. I am using the following interface

[grouping.interface.ts](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/models/grouping.interface.ts)

Comment: Your question is missing info, for example what code have you tried? You can't change change or customize what is sent by the onGroupChanged event and that is what SlickGrid (core) lib sends, if you want to add more properties (like the column def) then you'll need to contribute to the 6pac/SlickGrid open source project and then that will later be usable in Angular-Slickgrid. Please provide code sample and more info on the next time around if you don't want your questions to get closed.